# Regular Expression negative lookahead for Vowels

Tags: java, regex

I would like a Java regular expression string that finds all vowels in a string unless they:

1. are the first character or
2. the next character following an underscore

AREA_ID becomes
AR_ID

LONG_NAME becomes
LNG_NM

HOME_ALONE becomes
HM_ALN

I have played around with http://gskinner.com/RegExr and
I currently have the following regex that replaces all vowels except if it is the starting character

```
(?!^[AEIOU])[AEIOU]
```

I can't figure out how to get the second part (ignore vowel immediately following an underscore).

Comment: You probably want to use word boundaries (`\b`).

Comment: You need to indicate what language or tool you're using, because different regex-engines are different. Most engines that support lookahead (which you're using) also support lookbehind (which you need), but (for example) JavaScript's doesn't.

Comment: By the way, a nitpick: a regex doesn't "remove" anything or "replace" anything; it merely *matches*. Regex-based replacement functionality is found in many languages, but the regex itself isn't actually doing the replacing!

Comment: I updated the post based on your comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you're using JavaScript, in which case this will do:

```
(?!(?:^|_))_?[AEIOU]
```

However, if you're using a regex flavour that supports lookbehinds, try this:

```
(?<!^)(?<!_)[AEIOU]
```

Note that two lookbehinds are needed because a lookbehind must have a fixed length, which "either the start of the string or an underscore" does not.

Comment: Thank you.  I was using the wrong lookaround.  In this case, look behind is what I want, and not look ahead.